# Can a .net regex pattern reference the numeric value of a previous capture elsewhere in the pattern?

Tags: .net, regex

Is it possible to have a .net regex pattern that references the numeric value of a previously captured group in another part of the pattern?  I need to match strings that repeat the following format:

- 10-byte alpha key followed by 2-byte operator (subset of sql operators) followed by 5 integer digits followed by an n-byte value, where n = the integer value of the 5 integer digits.

EX String:
"key1      = 00004val1key2      <=00006value2key3      >=00011value_three"

Where val1 is 4-bytes, value2 is 6-bytes, value_three is 11-bytes, etc....  This string represents repeating set of criteria that I need to be able to parse and identify the following strings:

1st Criteria:
"key1", "= ", "val1"

2nd Criteria:
"key2", "<=", "value2"

3rd Criteria:
"key3", ">=", "value_three"

I've used .net regex's in the past and should be able to figure out parsing the key, operator and digits in a repeating pattern, but don't know how, or even if, it is possible to reference the numeric value of the digits (i.e. an integer with value of 4 for the string "00004") later in the pattern.

**Update 1**
Originally I was thinking that I needed a regex pattern such as:

```
^(?<criteria>(?<key>\w{10})(?<operator>(= |<=|>=))(?<value_length>\d{5})(?<value>\w{n}))+$
```

where the {n} quantifier in the "value" capturing group needs to have a value based on the value of the "value_length" capturing group, for each "criteria" captured.  If this is not the right way to think about forming the regex pattern, I can change to another approach that works.

Comment: i am not able to understand your question..and you should use the term `character` instead of a `byte`..

Comment: and how are you calculating the interger value of the 5 integer digits

Comment: sorry, I don't post very often. It's clear in my head but not coming across that way. If there is something specific I need to add to my posts, let me know.  I need a pattern to match repeating sequences of: 10-characters followed by 2-character sql operators followed by 5 decimal digits followed by a variable length of charaters, where the length is determined by the 5 decimal digits that were just matched. This pattern repeats until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead capture the required length string in the match itself till the next `\w{10}` and operator `(= |<=|>=)` using lookahead

```
string regex=@"(?<key>\w{10})(?<operator>(= |<=|>=))(?<value_length>\d{5})(?<value>.*?(?=\w{10}(= |<=|>=)|$))";
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input,regex,RegexOptions.Singleline))
{
    int vLen=int.Parse(m.Groups["value_length"].Value);
    string requiredString=m.Groups["value"].Value.Substring(0,vLen-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Haven't used lookahead before, but that looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my post, that it's not possible. There is something called Backreference in Regex, which may help you:

if you want to match `aba`, the *verbal pattern* for that would look like `value1 followed by another value, followed by value 1`, which can be build as a regular expression: `(a)b\1`, where `\1` references the match of the FIRST group that is matched.

But keep in mind, that  a regex using a backreference is actually no more regex, because a "regular language" does - per definition - not allow recursion, which is what is happending behind the szenes.
(part of the pattern needs to be evaluated before the complete pattern can be evaluated)